# WPF ContextMenu CommandBinding disabled

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

I have a button and a context menu bound to the same Command, when I start the app, the button is enabled, but the context menu item isn't (as I said, they're bound to the same command). The context menu item becomes enabled only after I click the button. Does anybody know why?

[This is the behavior.](http://screencast.com/t/mHocCpq45gT)

And this is the XAML:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:LocalCommandManager.ShowDialogCommand" CanExecute="CanExecuteShowDialogCommand" Executed="ShowDialogCommandExecuted" />
    <CommandBinding Command="local:LocalCommandManager.DontShowDialogCommand" CanExecute="CanExecuteDontShowDialogCommand" Executed="DontShowDialogCommandExecuted" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Command="local:LocalCommandManager.ShowDialogCommand" />
        <MenuItem Command="local:LocalCommandManager.DontShowDialogCommand" />
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
<Grid Background="Red">
    <Button Command="local:LocalCommandManager.ShowDialogCommand" Content="Show Dialog" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="6" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Command code:

```
public static class LocalCommandManager
{
    private static object syncRoot = new object();

    private static RoutedUICommand _showDialogCommand;
    public static RoutedUICommand ShowDialogCommand
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (_showDialogCommand == null)
                    _showDialogCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Show Dialog", "ShowDialogCommand", typeof(LocalCommandManager));
                return _showDialogCommand;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Command event handlers (in MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
private void CanExecuteShowDialogCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}

private void ShowDialogCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dialog");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the command?  What kind of command is it?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Done, let me know if that helps. It's a RoutedUICommand.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on your can execute to see if its being hit?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Yes. It's hit as soon as the app starts running, but the context menu item is still disabled. I even put an InvalidateRequerySuggested in the Loaded event handle, but did not help.

Comment: I noticed that you're registering the owner as `CommandManager` but your class is actually `LocalCommandManager`, typo?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Yes typo, I just fixed it, but the problem remains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF custom command in context menu are disabled until any button clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921712/wpf-custom-command-in-context-menu-are-disabled-until-any-button-clicked)

Comment: I just noticed it's an exact duplicate of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921712/wpf-custom-command-in-context-menu-are-disabled-until-any-button-clicked the solution is there too. Thanks Gorilla!

Comment: I was just looking at that, glad you found it! =)